# Как перейти на след строку в TextView и оставить предыдущее слово

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Хочу сделать так
Есть `EditText` и `TextView`. 
Я набираю в `EditText`  слово (например hello), оно выводится в `TextView`. Нужно сделать так, чтобы после написания любого другого слова в `EditText`(например car), слово hello оставалось в `TextView`, а слово car писалось на следующей строке

Пробовал `\n` - не получилось 
Прошу сильно не пинаться, я новичок
Хочу сделать что-то вроде чата по локалке. Чат будет хранится в обычном текстовом файле.

Comment: Покажите код разметки вашего `TextView` и как вы программно добавляете `\n`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы наверное ставите текст с помощью `setText`. В этом случае текст заменится. Чтобы его добавить непосредственно к уже имеющемуся используйте метод `append`

```
if (!textView.getText().isEmpty()) textView.append("\n"); //избегаем новой строки если ничего нет
textView.append(новая строка);
```